# How after pressing the button to show another window? sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

How after pressing the button to show another window with success message? 
in sweetalert2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to call another Swal inside the `then`. The simplest example is:

```
swal.fire({
  title: 'Input Text',
  input: 'text'
}).then(result => {
  swal.fire(`You wrote: ${result.value}`)
})
```

In this one, the value returned by the previous modal is re-used in the new one.

You can find plenty of examples at https://sweetalert2.github.io/